# After uninstall of Brew, terminal is still looking for path/profile? Is this a symlink? How do I delete?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, uninstallation

I am way out of my depth with Brew, I just installed it to run the Alfred Spotify Mini-player. Realising I had dipped my toe in things I do not understand I ran the uninstall script. Now when I open terminal I get this:

```
/Users/jon/.zprofile:2: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/jon/.zprofile:4: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/jon/.zprofile:10: command not found: brew`
```

How do I clean this up? Is this a sym link? It might not be an issue but stuff like this just reminds me how little I understand about the dark arts of computers. Many thanks in advance

(I uninstalled Brew using the code on Github.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the .zprofile file in /users/jon and deleted it and this seems to have solved the problem at login

I guess that was pretty obvious.